# Retrieve the state in scan() iterator?

Tags: rust, iterator

To obtain the partial sums of a sequence of integers, I can use `scan()` on the iterator like this:

```
let partial: Box<[u32]> =
    list
    .iter()
    .scan(0, |st, elem| {
        let ret = *st;
        *st += elem;
        Some(ret)
    })
    .collect();
```

The above code works well, but I'm trying to modify it to give me the total sum as well.

Something like:

```
let (partial, total): (Box<[u32]>, u32) =
    list
    .iter()
    .scan(0, |st, elem| {
        // TODO
    })
    .collect();
```

It seems like I would just need to obtain the eventual value of `st`, and the iterator should already know it's value.  However, I can't seem to find a way to retrieve that value, short of doing a second iteration over the whole sequence (e.g. with `fold()`).

Is there a way to find the partial sums and the total sum in a single pass?

Comment: Is it intentional that your first code snippet has a zero at the start and ignores the last element of the list? (i.e. for `list = [1, 2, 3, 4]`, the output is `[0, 1, 3, 6]`, ignoring the `4`.

Comment: @SCappella Yeah it is intentional.  I'm writing a compiler and the partial sum is to measure the offset of each element in a struct (ignoring alignment issues).  The total sum would then be the size of the struct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Include the total sum in the `scan`, but then split off the last value.

```
use std::iter;

fn main() {
    let list = vec![1, 2, 3, 4];

    // Add zero at the start to emulate what you had before
    let partial: Box<[u32]> = iter::once(0)
        .chain(list.iter().scan(0, |st, elem| {
            *st += elem;
            Some(*st)
        }))
        .collect();
    // unwrap since with the added zero, the slice will always be non-empty
    let (total, partial) = partial.split_last().unwrap();

    println!("partial sums: {:?}", partial);
    println!("total sum: {}", total);
}
```

[(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4b4ca91890460b899fbb341eb850d6e2)

---

Or using [`successors()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/fn.successors.html):

```rust
fn main() {
    use std::iter::successors;

    let list = vec![1, 2, 3, 4];

    let mut iter = list.iter();
    let partial: Vec<_> = successors(Some(0), |n| iter.next().map(|i| n + i)).collect();
    // unwrap since with the added zero, the slice will always be non-empty
    let (total, partial) = partial.split_last().unwrap();

    assert_eq!(partial, &[0, 1, 3, 6]);
    assert_eq!(total, &10);
}
```

[(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=da91ffbe84f42ba8ca77bee9d4178b1a)

Comment: This is probably the best answer in this case, but I eventually wrote a new iterator trait `scan_ref()` that takes the first argument by reference instead of value, which feels cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

You must decide what you want to do in the closure.

As it stands in your code, you remember `ret = *st` which is the accumulator's value *before* the addition takes place, and you return `Some(ret)`. Thus, the first item you get in the result is currently `0`.

If you want the value after the sums, you should just return `Some(*st)`, which is the updated accumulator's value *after* the addition.